# Compare some columns from some tables using python

Tags: python, csv

I need to compare two values `MC` and `JT` from 2 tables:

```
EID MolIdx TEStart TEEnd TE TZone TBulkBE TBulkAE MC JT zavg vabs vzavg  xyd.x xyd.y xydist nnbw vabsprev midhb
0 370 36700 36800 110 20 36150 37090 0 0 -8.25705 0.219113 -0.000800014 20.8926 41.4347 5.75852 0 4.13067 0 
1 423 17950 18150 210 180 17400 18430 1 0 -4.26426 0.586578 -0.053 77.22 85.2104 22.0534 0 3.551 0 
2 468 41790 42020 240 50 41360 42380 0 0 7.82681 0.181248 -0.00269566 90.0646 92.7698 5.0841 0 4.19304 0
```

and

```
EID MolIdx TEStart TEEnd TE TZone TBulkBE TBulkAE MC JT zavg vabs vzavg xyd.x xyd.y xydist nnbw vabsprev midhb
0 370 36700 36800 110 20 36150 37090 0 0 -0.846655 0.0218695 2.59898e-05 2.0724 4.1259 0.583259 10 0.412513 0 
1 423 17950 18150 210 180 17400 18780 1 0 -0.453311 0.058732 -0.00526783 7.7403 8.52544 2.19627 0 0.354126 0 
2 468 41790 42020 240 70 41360 42380 0 0 0.743716 0.0181613 -0.000256186 9.08777 9.21395 0.502506 0 0.419265 0
```

I need to do it using module `csv`. I know how to do it using `pandas` and `xlrd`, but using `csv` don't know.

Desire output:

```
Number_of_strings MC JT
```

And print strings, where values are different

```
import csv

old = csv.reader(open('old.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
row1 = old.next()
new = csv.reader(open('new.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
row2 = new.next()

if (row1[8] == row2[8]) and (row1[9] == row2[9]):
    continue
else:
    print row1[0] + ':' + row1[8] + '!=' + row2[8]
```

Comment: Please post your attempts. SO wont do your homework for you. [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I add my code to question

Comment: Your code has no valid syntax: `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`.

Comment: I try to change it, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
old = list(csv.reader(open('old.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=','))
new = list(csv.reader(open('new.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=','))

old = zip(*old)
new = zip(*new)

print ['%s-%s-%s'%(str(a), str(b), str(c)) for a, b, c in zip(old[0], new[8], old[8]) if b != c]
```

First, we get a list of lists. `zip(*x)` will *transpose* a list of lists. The rest should be easy to decipher ...

You can actually put whatever you want within the string ...

Comment: Why it returns `IndexError: list index out of range`?

Comment: If you are using ipython, print `zip(*old)` to see what you get. Its probably a minor read error. Is your file comma separated or space separated?

Comment: Or better still first print `old` and `new` to see if you are reading data correctly ...

Comment: when I `print ``old = zip(*old)` it returns `[('EID', '0 370 36700 36800 110 20 36150 37090 0 0 -0.846655 0.0218695 2.59898e-05 2.0724 4.1259 0.583259 10 0.412513 0 ',` and next all strings

Comment: Your file isn't comma separated. First you need to check what your file looks like before you can use the csv module. You need to use the right `delimiter` to read the file correctly. You said that you could do it with Pandas. How did you read that? `pandas.read_csv`?